# Android Beta App - Google Play Error message

Tags: android, api, sdk, apk, google-play

I need some assistance. I've published my beta version to the Google Play Store and using the beta link I keep getting the message "Your device isnt compatible with this version".

I checked and rechecked all my settings and my phone which I've built and tested this app cannot download through the store. I'm sure its narrowed down to my Manifest file but unsure what I'm still doing wrong.

I've removed the targetSDK, never used the maxSDK as suggested by Google best practices and uses a minimumSDK of 14 because of certain features the app uses. Am I missing things?

My phone: HTC Droid DNA Android v: 4.1.1 HTC SDK API Level: 4.63

Any help is so greatly appreciated.

```
<!--    Version History:
            1.0 - Original - 7/28/13
            2 - ScreenSize allowance expanded - 8/1/13
            4 - set targetSDK to 14 and max to 17 - 8/1/13
            5 - removed targetSDK - 8/2/13
            6 - n/a not directly related to manifest
            -->


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: There seemed to be an issue with the API level and the screen android sections were no longer supported in certain API's. Added this:     <supports-screens
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"/>